# how to run a user command from a script

Tags: vlc-media-player, shell-script

I have to run a vlc command, which cant be run as root. I am logged in as root. I want to put the command in a script ( shell script ) and run the command. How can I do this.My script is

```
    #!/bin/sh
su - user 
vlc -vvv bigbuck.mp4 --sout '#rtp{dst=99.195.203.99,port=8090,sdp=rtsp://99.195.203.99:8091/test.sdp}' &
```

If I from command promt, I do su - user and run the vlc command, it works but I put those in the shell script, then not working. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run `vlc` as another user, use:

```
#!/bin/sh
su user -c 'vlc -vvv bigbuck.mp4 --sout "#rtp{dst=99.195.203.99,port=8090,sdp=rtsp://99.195.203.99:8091/test.sdp}" &
```

If you don't need the graphic interface, you might consider using `cvlc` in place of `vlc`:

```
#!/bin/sh
su user -c 'cvlc -vvv bigbuck.mp4 --sout "#rtp{dst=99.195.203.99,port=8090,sdp=rtsp://99.195.203.99:8091/test.sdp}" &
```

#### Discussion

When one runs `su - user` at the command line, it opens a shell under user's account.  You can then enter interactively into that shell.  When writing a shell script with `su`, the trick is to use the `-c` option so that the command is run as user.

Consider:

```
#!/bin/sh
su - user 
vlc -vvv bigbuck.mp4 --sout '#rtp{dst=99.195.203.99,port=8090,sdp=rtsp://99.195.203.99:8091/test.sdp}' &
```

The command `su - user` will open a login shell under user's account.  Only after that shell exits will the `vlc` command run.  This is not what you want and that is why the `-c` option is needed.

#### Documention

The `-c` option to `su` is documented in `man su`:

```
   -c, --command COMMAND
       Specify a command that will be invoked by the shell using its -c.

       The executed command will have no controlling terminal. This option
       cannot be used to execute interractive programs which need a
       controlling TTY.
```